# How to add a title to a Seaborn boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I've tried both `sns.boxplot('Day', 'Count', data= gg).title('lalala')` and `sns.boxplot('Day', 'Count', data= gg).suptitle('lalala')`. None worked. I think it might be because I'm also working with Matplotlib.

It seems pretty googleable, but I haven't been able to find something online that works.

Answer (score 321):

A Seaborn box plot returns a Matplotlib *axes* instance. Unlike pyplot itself, which has a method `plt.title()`, the corresponding argument for an *axes* is `ax.set_title()`. Therefore you need to call

```
sns.boxplot('Day', 'Count', data=gg).set_title('lalala')
```

A complete example would be:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.boxplot(x=tips["total_bill"]).set_title("LaLaLa")

plt.show()
```

Of course you could also use the returned axes instance to make it more readable:

```
ax = sns.boxplot('Day', 'Count', data=gg)
ax.set_title('lalala')
ax.set_ylabel('lololo')
```

Comment: its a shame `set_title()` and similar functions do not `return self`, that would be neat.

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol Matplotlib's credo is to return the object that the method creates or manipulates. This is a question of flexibility; and matplotlib explicitely wants to give users this flexibility. More high-level APIs that sit on top of matplotlib often decide to allow for chaining, but in those cases you have problems manipulating the underlying objects when wanting some non-standard behaviour.

Comment: when combining the various interfaces matplotlib has I definitely agree

Comment: AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'set_title'

Comment: @DumbML are you sure you were using a `boxpot`?  This doesn't work with every graph generating method of seaborn.  Particularly, I tried this with `lmplot` and it didn't work. (Same error)

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol that would be untypical for python though: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2003-October/038855.html

Answer (score 65):

The sns.boxplot() function returns an Axes(matplotlib.axes.Axes) object. Please refer the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html).

You can add a title using 'set' method as below:

```
sns.boxplot('Day', 'Count', data=gg).set(title='lalala')
```

You can also add other parameters, like xlabel and ylabel to the *set* method:

```
sns.boxplot('Day', 'Count', data=gg).set(title='lalala', xlabel='its x_label', ylabel='its y_label')
```

There are some other methods as mentioned in the [matplotlib.axes.Axes documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#axis-labels-title-and-legend) to add tile, legend and labels.

Comment: This is a nice solution since it also works for `sns.relplot()`.

Answer (score 41):

Try adding this at the end of your code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.title('add title here')
```

Comment: perhaps the best solution, sure not purely sns -ish, but hustle free and simple. Thanks

Comment: Undisputedly the best solution

Answer (score 16):

For a single boxplot:

```
import seaborn as sb
sb.boxplot(data=Array).set_title('Title')
```

For more boxplots in the same plot:

```
import seaborn as sb
sb.boxplot(data=ArrayofArray).set_title('Title')
```

For example,

```
import seaborn as sb
myarray = [78.195229, 59.104538, 19.884109, 25.941648, 72.234825, 82.313911]
sb.boxplot(data=myarray).set_title('myTitle')
```

Answer (score 8):

**.set_title('')** can be used to add a title to a Seaborn plot:

```
import seaborn as sb
sb.boxplot().set_title('Title')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import seaborn as sns
g = sns.catplot(x='Day', y='Count', data=gg)
g.set_title('LaLa')
```

Comment: Re *"Try this"*: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? How is it different from previous answers? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72836377/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).