# Seaborn Scatterplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

There are two main things I would like to do for my scatterplot in seaborn.

1. Change the Legend Title and remove the series name from the legend. So remove the `petal_length` that appears in legend
2. Change the numeric output for the legend. Change to the range [0,4,8]

How do I do that?

```
import seaborn as sns
cmap = sns.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True)
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
p=sns.scatterplot("sepal_length", "sepal_width",data=iris
                  ,hue="petal_length"
                  ,palette = cmap
                  )
p.set(xlabel='Sepal Len', ylabel='Sepal Width')
p.legend(title="Petal Length")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding title to the plot
[How to add title to seaborn boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42406233/how-to-add-title-to-seaborn-boxplot/42409861)

Removing legend title:
[Remove seaborn lineplot legend title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51579215/remove-seaborn-lineplot-legend-title)

Changing how the legend 'buckets':
You have set hue to a column of the data. I would bucket the length into the groups I want in a new column, then set the hue to the new column.

Comment: I should have clarified. I am trying to remove the legend title 'petal_length' not add a Plot Title. I have changed the question to reflect that.

Comment: please read the accepted answer, especially the part with this code: handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles=handles[1:], labels=labels[1:])

Answer (score 0):

With `get_legend_handles_labels()` you can get a list of the handles and the labels meant to go in the legend.  Then, you can create the legend skipping every other element of both the handles and the labels.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

cmap = sns.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True)
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
ax = sns.scatterplot("sepal_length", "sepal_width", data=iris, hue="petal_length", palette=cmap)
ax.set_xlabel('Sepal Len'),
ax.set_ylabel('Sepal Width')
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles[1::2], labels[1::2], title="Petal Length")
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Does this answer your question?